# Hover pseudo-class affects other elements

Tags: html, css, hover

I wrote the hover pseudo-class for all input and label elements as shown in the image ,but when when I hover my mouse on one label the other indent directly to the right

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks0yt.png)

The code is shown:

```
<Style>
    label {
width: 180px;
float: left;
text-align: right;
margin-right: 0.1em;
display:inline-block;
}
label[type:checkbox]+[type:radio]{
    width: auto;
input:hover { font-size:25px }
label:hover { font-size:25px }
</style>
```

Comment: You did not close your `{` here `label[type:checkbox]+[type:radio]{`

Comment: user hover on label or input -> font size increase -> no space for the following element -> the following element get pushed to the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should make clear that your markup is valid. As already mentioned in the comments, you forgot a curly brace `{` for your `label[type...]` descriptor.

To avoid the shifting of other elements on hover, you should make clear, that the hovered label height doesn't become greater than the height of the input element next to it. Therefore the `line-height` of the label and the `height` of the inputs should at least be `25px`.

Since you haven't provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the exact code is hard to guess, but the following should work:

```css
input {
  height: 25px; /* <- */
}
label {
  width: 180px;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 0.1em;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 25px; /* <- */
}
label[type:checkbox]+[type:radio] {
  width: auto;
}
input:hover {
  font-size: 25px
}
label:hover {
  font-size: 25px
}
```

Comment: It worked but the my radio element (male&female) indented badly , you can see it directly from this link:

Comment: As I already said, without your complete code its hard to guess the right solution...

Comment: Here is the code in a google doc, please view it in your code editor for highlited code 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jQxd-fy452y2xuQZfMSf0S4HnUsRxwyYbVX-c4RQgLY

Comment: Here is the code in a google doc, please view it in your code editor for highlighted code :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jQxd-fy452y2xuQZfMSf0S4HnUsRxwyYbVX-c4RQgLY